# Why wont my div vertical-align?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've <strike>literally</strike> metaphorically looked everywhere and I still can't seem to make it work..

I was previously programming on Microsoft Edge which looked fine, and worked fine.. But when i uploaded it and people started using chrome, firefox etc... It would do this:

[image: Vertical align not working (left side of image)]

Here's the code I'm using to align it:

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

And here is the JSFiddle for a better overview of what I'm doing: http://jsfiddle.net/wc1f8ewd/

(EDIT) Click on the cod logo or league logo to see the problem

Comment: Which div are you referring to?...and align to what?

Comment: I'm using the latest Firefox and looks fine to me?

Comment: Looks okay for me. Windows 10 Latest GChrome: http://i.imgur.com/CeWGMDF.png?1

Comment: The same problem can be viewed at http://aveera.tv (Click on the cod div) as shown in the photo

Comment: I presume you mean when clicking an image, the boxes that show should then be in the same place as the image was

Comment: Exactly @DarrenSweeney

Comment: How about stripping all that code down to a minimum example? We shouldn't have to load the page and click a logo to see the resultant issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this vertical-align trick to work, you need to specify the height of the container. Add:

```
.cod-main, .league-main {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a relatively positioned div with `top: 50%;`, this will make it 50% of the height of the relative div not the wrapping element.

Change this to absolute position and apply the same `left: 50%` and transform property.

updated your fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/wc1f8ewd/1/

```
    .cod-options {
        display: none;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        position: absolute;
}
```